# Is there a way to get the equivalent of a pip freeze from a wheel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

I have a situation where I am doing the following in CI:

```
pip3 wheel -r requirements.txt
```

I would like to get a list of all the deps that requires (including transitive ones).

The only way I can think of is to make a throwaway virtual environment pip install from the wheel and then do pip freeze from that virtual environment.

This seems undesirable in a CI process so I am hoping there is a way to remove that pip install step and instead get a list of all the deps directly from the wheel / requirements.txt.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way because of recursive ("transitive") dependencies. There is no way to query for dependencies remotely so `pip` has at least to download packages to inspect their list of dependencies.

And where from `pip freeze` could get a list of installed packages? Your transient virtualenv seems to be the only way.